# What happens to Deadpool's severed limbs?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

In Deadpool the movie we see him cut his hand off,

And we know that Deadpool has regenerating powers an that he can even regenerate from a single living cell, so what happens to the hand that colossus has?

What happens to his hand?

Comment: Depends on the time period it used to be that he would need his brain to activate his healing factor (so if you like grinded him into mush or exploded him he would die). But the evil Deadpool thing is a pretty cool idea and with how they are currently doing *[Madcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madcap_(comics))* in the comics, it seems like he could literally regrow from mush.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In the comics his severed parts are collected by an avid fan. When there's sufficient of them, they grow into a new Deadpool, but [one that's evil](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Evil_Deadpool_(Earth-616))...

[image]

[image]

Comment: And *this*, ladies and gents, is why you never leave DNA evidence laying around!

Comment: Could someone do the same with Wolverine?

Comment: @Jamil Presumably, since their healing factors work essentially the same way. That's probably worth its own question.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you keep it more practical, then, you know, deadpool needs mass & energy to regenerate his organs. But for the detached limbs and other things, that mass & energy - which in case of deadpool's main body, comes from the foods he been eating or stored in body - isn't enough to regenerate a whole new body. But if his detached parts get evolved and if cells can absorb the energy&mass required, acting as single metabolisms or alike, then i think it is not impossible to regenerate a whole new & bulky body to entertain us :D

Comment: What do you mean when you say "get evolved"?

Comment: Practical? Deadpool? What are you talking about, sir.

Comment: I mean EVOLUTION. Like viruses do, unlike any other organism, rapid and mysterious evolution of a single limb - detached from body. Evolving hence reproducting itself to a better, bulky, beasty orgnanism having a metabolism that absorbs mass from soil or whatever place it is lying or floating on and generates energy by leading nuclear fission of materials it absorbed!

Comment: This might seem million light years from practical ground but it is deadpool, right? :D So, redefine the world "practical", fussioning with "possibility".

Comment: Only species evolve. An individual (or a detached part) doesn't.

Comment: Yes . After Mr.Darwin said that evolution thing that freaked out church guys, people are following him. But no one has ever said anything new freaky since. I'm glad that I'm challanging your beliefs and your logical assesments with my imagination. What is the point in the term "Science-Fiction", if you insist "fiction" to stay in a small dog house? I'd say, let "fiction" have the whole pent house!! And scince be his b!tc# :D