# In which comic did Deadpool have the face of Tom Cruise?

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, deadpool

I saw a panel once where Deadpool was cursed by Loki to look like Tom Cruise.

Why did he curse him, and what happened after that ?

Comment: Marvel Wikia says it happened in Deadpool #37-45. http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Glossary:Curse - You can see the panel [here](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/c/c2/Wade_Wilson_from_Deadpool_Vol_1_37_0002.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/180?cb=20151118164955).

Comment: For future reference - if you know the series or character the work you're looking for belongs to, you use `episode-identification`

Comment: @Valorum I swear I saw this somewhere on this Stack...

Comment: When I read the question title I figured he was keeping it in his freezer or something.

Comment: @DanSmolinske - [Oh yeah?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/137819/20774)

Comment: Because if you were Tom Cruise you'd be the only one on earth who couldn't enjoy Tom Cruise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This occurs in Deadpool Vol 1. (issues [#037-45](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_Vol_1_37)). After Deadpool refuses to accept that Loki is his father(!), Loki curses him and says that he'll "*ruin his life until he accepts the truth and seeks his father's forgiveness*".

[image]
**#037**

Surprisingly the way he does this is by making him *so* handsome that his good looks become a burden (a pain I know *only too well*).

[image]
**#037**

[image]
**#038**

Note that he is said to look like "Thom Cruz", rather than real-world Tom Cruise as you remembered (probably to avoid lawsuits).

Deadpool's curse is lifted when he

> Accidentally apologises to his *real* father.
>  [image]
>  [image]
> **#045**

Comment: Why did Loki place this terrible curse on Deadpool?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - See edit. It was a punishment for Deadpool not accepting Loki as his father.

Comment: Why is Loki suddenly Deadpool's father?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - That sounds like a new question since it relates to an earlier serial

Comment: Nah, too lazy to ask.